# Pandas conditionally change cells with regex

Tags: regex, pandas, apply

I have a data frame with some cell values such as $1,245 which are interpreted as objects.

How can I write a lambda function to remove the '$' and ',' and cast to float in only cells whose entry contains a '$'?

I was able to get it working without the if-else before. but that also messed up other string columns that do not have $ in them.

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[$,]', 
'').astype(float) if '$' in x else x)
```

Sample Data:

```
Programmer, Hawaii,"$115,887","$9,657","$2,229",$55.72
Engineering Manager, West Virginia,"$115,420","$9,618","$2,220",$55.49
Data Scientist, Pennsylvania,"$114,863","$9,572","$2,209",$55.22
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: added sample data to question, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [**`replace()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to use `regex=True` with a raw `r`-string and change the filter to test `x.str.contains('[$,]').all()`:

```py
df = (df.apply(lambda x:
    x.str.replace(r'[$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
    if x.str.contains('[$,]').all() else x))

#                      0               1         2       3       4      5
# 0           Programmer          Hawaii  115887.0  9657.0  2229.0  55.72
# 1  Engineering Manager   West Virginia  115420.0  9618.0  2220.0  55.49
# 2       Data Scientist    Pennsylvania  114863.0  9572.0  2209.0  55.22
```

You can also [**`applymap()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) by chaining 2x `replace()`:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: float(x.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')) if '$' in x else x)
```

Comment: No need to chain 2x `replace()` — as in my answer, you can use regex in the same way.

Comment: @k_n_c With `applymap`, the lambda receives a `string`, not a `Series`. `string.replace` does not support regex.